# validate service connection: validate CRI v1 image API for endpoint

Tags: kubernetes

Today when I use this crictl `crictl version v1.28.0` command to pull image in CentOS 7.9:

```
[root@k8sslave01 ~]# crictl pull registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6
WARN[0000] image connect using default endpoints: [unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock unix:///run/crio/crio.sock unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock]. As the default settings are now deprecated, you should set the endpoint instead.
ERRO[0000] validate service connection: validate CRI v1 image API for endpoint "unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock": rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial unix /var/run/dockershim.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
E1122 16:47:19.799530   31559 remote_image.go:180] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to do request: Head \"https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6\": dial tcp 142.250.157.82:443: i/o timeout" image="registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6"
FATA[0030] pulling image: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to do request: Head "https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6": dial tcp 142.250.157.82:443: i/o timeout
```

I have checked the `/etc/containerd/config.toml` and make sure the cri is enabled and look like this :

```
#   Copyright 2018-2022 Docker Inc.

#   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#   You may obtain a copy of the License at

#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

#   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#   limitations under the License.

#disabled_plugins = ["cri"]

#root = "/var/lib/containerd"
#state = "/run/containerd"
#subreaper = true
#oom_score = 0
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
   config_path = "/etc/containerd/certs.d"

#[grpc]
#  address = "/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
#  uid = 0
#  gid = 0

#[debug]
#  address = "/run/containerd/debug.sock"
#  uid = 0
#  gid = 0
#  level = "info"
```

this is the containerd version info:

```
[root@k8sslave01 ~]# containerd -v
containerd containerd.io 1.6.24 61f9fd88f79f081d64d6fa3bb1a0dc71ec870523
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? I have already tried to restart the containerd:

```
systemctl restart containerd
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found I should add configuration `/etc/crictl.yaml`:

```
runtime-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
image-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
timeout: 10
#debug: true
debug: false
```